# Retrieving a file name to attach to an email with SwiftMailer and PHP

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I asked the question yesterday and got an advice, and used it, but it doesn't work for some reason.
So, I need to retrieve the name of the file that was uploaded to my server from an HTML form by a user. I need this file to be attached to an email that is to be sent by PHP/SwiftMailer.
Here is my code, the file upload portion:

```
    //File upload

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/";

// Add the original filename to our target path.  
//Result is "uploads/filename.extension" 
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}   

//End of file upload
```

This is the file attaching portion:

```
//Create the attachment
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
```

Why doesn't it get the file from the server? 
Here is the error message, and it looks like it's trying to find the file in a wrong directory:

> Warning: fopen(/tmp/phpHJdw0H)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/myserver/mydomain.com/Hawaii/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php
>   on line 131
>   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Unable to open file for reading [/tmp/phpHJdw0H]' in /home/myserver/mydomain.com/Hawaii/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php:133 Stack trace: #0
>   etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($target_path);
```

This is because you have moved the file from its temporary location, `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']` returns the path from before you moved the file using [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). This assumes the `$target_path` is within scope to the swift mailer code