# Mail dynamically created .ics file attachment unable to open file for reading

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, icalendar, swiftmailer

**Environment:**
 - Laravel 5.3

**Case:**
Mail about an 'event' including an attachment with an iCalendar file (`.ics`). The `ics` file is being generated using `PHP`.

**Problem:**
While sending the mail *with* the `ics` file Laravel returns the following error:

> **Swift_IoException** in FileByteStream.php line 144:
>   Unable to open file for reading [/storage/app/public/events/eventname.ics]

The generated file seems fine while using it without the mail. The event gets added to the calendar so the file is not corrupt. While debugging (`dd` on the path) the file is getting returned, so folder/access permissions seems fine either.

**Code:**

```
// Build mail
public function build()
{
    $event = $this->createEvent($this->data[2]->planned_at, $this->data[2]->subject, $this->data[2]->content);

    return $this->view('emails.template')
        ->from('info@stackoverflow.nl', 'Stackoverflow')->subject($this->data[2]->subject)
        ->with([
            'token' => $this->data[0],
            'email' => $this->data[1],
            'mail' => $this->data[2],
            'sponsors' => $this->data[3],
            'name' => $this->data[4],

        ])
        ->attach(Storage::url('app/public/events/' . $this->data[2]->subject . '.ics'), [
            'as' => $this->data[2]->subject . '.ics',
            'mime' => 'calendar/event',
        ]);
}

// Build ics file
static function createEvent($date, $subject, $content)
{
    $dateTimeArr = explode(' ', $date);
    $newDate = $dateTimeArr[0];
    $dateArr = explode('-', $newDate);
    $newDate = $dateArr[0] . $dateArr[1] . $dateArr[2] . '-' . $dateTimeArr[1];
    $date = substr($newDate, 0, -9);

    $startTime = str_replace(":", "", substr($newDate, 9, -3));

    $strip = str_replace("\r", "", strip_tags($content));
    $desc = str_replace("\n", "", $strip);

    // ICS
    $mail[0] = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR";
    $mail[1] = "-//WEBSITE v1.0//NL";
    $mail[2] = "VERSION:2.0";
    $mail[3] = "METHOD:PUBLISH";
    $mail[4] = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR";
    $mail[5] = "DTSTART:" . $date . "T" . $startTime . "00Z";
    $mail[6] = "DTEND:" . $date . "T" . $startTime . "00Z";
    $mail[7] = "DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd') . 'T' . gmdate('His') . "Z";
    $mail[8] = "UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    $mail[9] = "ORGANIZER;" . "Stackoverflow";
    $mail[10] = "CREATED:" . $date . "T" . $startTime . "00Z";
    $mail[11] = "DESCRIPTION:" . $desc;
    $mail[12] = "LAST-MODIFIED:" . $date . "T" . $startTime . "00Z";
    $mail[13] = "LOCATION:" . "";
    $mail[14] = "SEQUENCE:0";
    $mail[15] = "STATUS:CONFIRMED";
    $mail[16] = "SUMMARY:" . "";
    $mail[17] = "TRANSP:OPAQUE";
    $mail[18] = "END:VEVENT";
    $mail[19] = "END:VCALENDAR";

    //set correct content-type-header
    $filename = $subject . '.ics';
    $mail = implode("\r\n", $mail);

    header("text/calendar");

    Storage::put('public/events/' . $filename , $mail);
}
```

Comment: Could be a permissions issue, does the server process user have access to the the /storage/app/public/events/ folder?

Comment: While 'dd'ing the storage path the file is getting returned, so the file is being accessed correctly

Comment: If my answer resolved you problem please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

A number of similar tickets have suggested that you need to pass the real path to swiftmailer.

Something like this:

```
public function build()
{
$event = $this->createEvent($this->data[2]->planned_at, $this->data[2]->subject, $this->data[2]->content);
$path=realpath('app/public/events/' . $this->data[2]->subject . '.ics');
return $this->view('emails.template')
    ->from('info@stackoverflow.nl', 'Stackoverflow')->subject($this->data[2]->subject)
    ->with([
        'token' => $this->data[0],
        'email' => $this->data[1],
        'mail' => $this->data[2],
        'sponsors' => $this->data[3],
        'name' => $this->data[4],

    ])
    ->attach($path), [
        'as' => $this->data[2]->subject . '.ics',
        'mime' => 'calendar/event',
    ]);
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unable-to-open-file-for-reading-swift-ioexception

[PHP, Swift-mailer problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531180/php-swift-mailer-problem)

[Retrieving a file name to attach to an email with SwiftMailer and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290966/retrieving-a-file-name-to-attach-to-an-email-with-swiftmailer-and-php)

Comment: Realpath always returns false, tried multiple different paths as parameter

Comment: This is assuming that the your filesystem is correctly setup https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem  `Remember, if you are using the local driver, all files that should be publicly accessible should be placed in the storage/app/public directory. Furthermore, you should create a symbolic link at public/storage which points to the storage/app/public directory.`

Comment: I know, and that the file is found. BUT. Realpath returns false every time.

Comment: Realpath uses filesystem paths - you have to pass it the full path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462006/php-real-path-always-returning-false

Comment: Ah okay, gotcha. It works now. Is there a way to prevent using realpath? Otherwise the path needs to be changed everytime we switch from virtual machine to live server and so forth?

Comment: I think thats beyond the scope of this question take a look at the laravel docs for environment configuration  - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration